# Compile partial SCSS-Files with Sass-Globbing in Jetbrains IDE

Tags: css, sass, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher, sass-globbing

I just installed the [sass-globbing-plugin](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing) to import partials recursively from a folder automatically.

Currently I am using the newest version of jetbrains pycharm. To activate sass-globbing to the existing scss-filewatcher, I edited the arguments for the scss-compiler:

```
-r sass-globbing --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Now I can compile my scss recursively, but only if I make changes to the root file, where i do my import statement with the sass-globbing. Is it possible to trigger the scss-compiler on a change inside of one of the imported scss-partials, like before with globbing enabled?

Comment: I think Jetbrain do this by default and no need to additional config. Please reset your config

Answer (score 0):

With "**track only root files**" enabled, the IDE follows SASS imports chain to find the 'main' file from a partial and pass it to compiler, so that no separate `.css` files are produced for partials and all changes are merged into the main `.css` file. But it knows nothing about file globbing and can't resolve imports when using glob patterns, that's why file watcher is not triggered